# looping through two seq declarations

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create F5 commands using a bash script which loops through two sequence declarations, one for IP address and the other is for the VLAN, which I then concatenate at the end.

```
#!/bin/bash

vlan_seq=$(seq 1010 1010;seq 1012 1024;seq 1054 1054;seq 1146 1161)
ip_seq=$(seq 10 10;seq 12 24;seq 54 54;seq 146 161)

for i in $ip_seq; do

ip_part=$(echo net self 10.189.${i}.1 "{" address 10.189.${i}.1/24)

done

for e in $vlan_seq; do

vlan_part=$(echo floating enabled traffic-group traffic-group-1 unit 1 vlan 
vlan_${e}_int_compute "}")

done

echo ${ip_part} ${vlan_part}
```

This seems to be working but I'm just getting the last result and I'm a bit stuck at how to approach this. What should I loop through to get all the results?

net self 10.189.161.1 { address 10.189.161.1/24 floating enabled traffic-group traffic-group-1 unit 1 vlan vlan_1161_int_compute }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to find a better way to do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

vlan_seq=($(seq 1010 1010;seq 1012 1024;seq 1054 1054;seq 1146 1161))
ip_seq=($(seq 10 10;seq 12 24;seq 54 54;seq 146 161))

for ((i=0;i<${#ip_seq[@]};++i)); do

  printf "net self 10.189.%s.1 { address 10.189.%s.1/24 floating enabled traffic-group traffic-group-1 unit 1 vlan vlan_%s_int_compute }\n" 
"${ip_seq[i]}" "${ip_seq[i]}" "${vlan_seq[i]}"

done
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need two sequences?  It looks like the entries in `vlan_seq` are all 1000 more than the corresponding entries in `ip_seq`.

So we can just compute it for each `$i`:

```
#!/bin/bash

format=$(printf '%s\\n' \
         'self 10.189.%d.1 { address 10.189.%d.1/24' \
         '                   floating enabled' \
         '                   traffic-group traffic-group-1' \
         '                   unit 1' \
         '                   vlan vlan_%d_int_compute' \
         '}')


ip_seq=(10 {12..24} 54 {164..161})

for i in ${ip_seq[@]}; do
    printf "$format" $i $i $((1000+i))
done
```